# Java Regex - Trying to create a specific pattern but I'm not quite sure what to do

Tags: java, regex

In my Java application, I'm trying to specify a Pattern that would match anything that's not made up of either uppercase letters, lowercase letters, or dashes. So I want it to match anything that doesn't contain A-Z, a-z, or '-'. I'm new to using regular expressions so I just wanted to see if I was even close to getting this right. This is what I have:

```
Pattern.compile("[^A-Z]&&[^a-z]&&[^\\-]");
```

I'm not even sure if I need the escape characters for the dash or if I do, whether it should be two backslashes instead of one. I'm also not sure about the format overall. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Made up of characters, _none_ of which are upper, lower, or dashes?  Or made up of characters, at least one of which isn't a upper, lower, or a dash.

Comment: If you are not sure just try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building off of @Joe's answer:

```
Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z\\-]");
```

But you need to use double backlash since you need to escape the `\` which is escaping the `-`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to say "AND NOT", you can just lump them all in together:

```
Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z\-]");
```

With regards to escaping, a single backslash `\` escapes the character immediately after it, so `\-` gives you a textual `-` character, and `\\` gives you a textual `\` character. In your original post, the `\\-` escapes the backslash but not the hyphen, so you end up matching "not backslash or hyphen".

Comment: You're forgetting about the **Java** compiler.  The string literal `"\\-"` comprises an escaped backslash followed by a hyphen.  When the Java source is compiled, it becomes the string `\-`, which the *regex* compiler (`Pattern.compile()`) sees as an escaped hyphen.  The string literal `"\-"` won't get past the Java compiler.  To match a literal backslash followed by a hyphen, you have to use "\\\\-".

Comment: In any case, you don't heed to escape the hyphen if it's the last character listed in the character class, as in your example.